# Como reproducir simultaneamente dos streams de audio PCM en un DMA

Tags: c, stream, audio

Estoy trabajando en un proyecto en la tarjeta stm32f769i-disco, la cual tiene que correr un videojuego hecho por mi. La parte gráfica esta resuelta, donde tengo problemas es al querer reproducir dos o mas archivos wav no se cual es la forma correcta de sumarlos en un único stream para ese si enviarlo al DMA y que llegue al codec en dicha tarjeta.

¿Cual es el algoritmo que debo seguir para mas de un stream?

PD: Se reproducir un único stream mediante dma con doble buffer.